# Why can't I debug/step-into FormsAuthentication.Authenticate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2010, forms-authentication

I am having some trouble with active directory authentication using `FormsAuthentication` in ASP.NET MVC 2 (VS 2010).

As I understand it I should be able to step into/through the Microsoft source code for `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` if I check 'Enable source server support' and 'Enable .Net Framework source stepping' in  Options->Debug->General and specify 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' in Options->Debug->Symbols.

I have done this and can step into a whole bunch of MS source code, but not `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate`. The debugger simple steps over it.

Can anyone tell me why this is? If I could step into `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` it would make my life a whole lot easier.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that the problem lies within the FormsAuthentication class? I would imagine you'd be better served by looking for examples of AD authentication using ASP.NET MVC that are undoubtedly out there on the web.

Comment: I have read the online examples but have hit a problem - hence I am now trying to debug... Its the debugging that I am hiving problems with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my stupid.

I should have been using Membership.ValidateUser NOT FormsAuthentication.Authenticate.

My problems are all solved :)

However, I never figured out why I could not step into FormsAuthentication.Authenticate. I guess it will remain a mystery...

Comment: Question: Rep=5, Answer: Rep=28 This looks weird - haven't you your account merged? If not you should ask a moderator to do so.